# Facebook AdPreview not rendering

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to display an AdPreview for a sponsored post using the [AdPreview plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/ad-preview-plugin/). I already have the AdGroups created, as well as the corresponding AdCreatives, and so I know exactly what `creative_id`/`ad_id` I need to use to generate a preview off it.

I do as the docs say:

1. Load their plugin script, initialized with `xfbml=1` and `appId=<myAppId>`
2. Include the required HTML/XFBML where I want the preview to be displayed

so I have it like:

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/xfbml.adpreview.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxx";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- other elements -->
  <div class="fb-ad-preview" data-creative-id="1234567890" data-page-type="desktopfeed"></div>
  <!-- other elements -->
</body>
```

but when I load the page where I'm supposed to see this preview rendered, I only see an `iframe` appended inside `.fb-ad-preview`. This iframe points to a URL like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/ad_preview.php?app_id=xxxxxxxxxx&channel=http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/LEdxGgtB9cN.js?version=40#cb=f2a62e0788&domain=www.mycustomdomain.com&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycustomdomain.com%3A8000%2Ff12be91bcc&relation=parent.parent&creative_id=1234567890&locale=en_US&page_type=desktopfeed&sdk=joey
```

which only loads some scripts that **do absolutely nothing; not even throwing errors at all**.

However, I see a difference with the iframe in the plugin page: in the plugin page, in the `src` of the generated iframe, the `channel` querystring param points to `https://s-static.ak.facebook.com` instead of `http://static.ak.facebook.com`.

When I visit my original url, but changing the subdomain to `https://s-static.ak.facebook.com`, a red, error-like box is displayed with a message `This plugin requires the use of the JavaScript SDK and XFBML.` :/

[image: This plugin requires the use of the JavaScript SDK and XFBML]

My Facebook application configuration has only `www.mycustomdomain.com` in `App domains` and `http://www.mycustomdomain.com:8000` (I'm building my webapp on python/django btw) and the app is not in "sandbox" mode.

So I wonder two things:

1. Why, in the first place, is the plugin using a different channel for me?
2. Why is it not rendering the HTML as it does in the plugin page?

I'm lost here, does somebody have any idea what's going on? Any help will be appreciated, please feel free to ask for details I might be missing to mention.

Answer (score 5):

The API solution actually worked for me, without having to specify all the parts of the preview. For any of the following endpoints, you can simply attach `page_type=desktopfeed` (as the docs say, silly me) as a querystring parameter

```
GET    https://graph.facebook.com/{adgroup_id}/previews
GET    https://graph.facebook.com/{ad_creative_id}/previews
GET    https://graph.facebook.com/act_{adaccount_id}/generatepreviews
```

and you'll be given the HTML code for an iframe which points to the actual preview:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "body": "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/preview_iframe.php?d=AQLEixbRWLC3D1fEIwqSC69Xs_sCLACoJtNu11HDSPSs_lSkeIrPrtAyxB7HvaPJX5_39KZb1I42Atny-Un3FVRq-6ls_nOp0DtKAhpBndpsFNq0PVb5b1KtjhdkdVrnRSgpPjlrAP2PtJp93u1XNA2QY3pJ_uncMRJPQaSsYjmVFCQ32lp0elUgSEIE8hCoNiEg&amp;t=Adj42KsfL7T-FYEG\" width=\"540\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"yes\" style=\"border: none;\"></iframe>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Embed that in your pege wherever you want it to be displayed, just **be careful about ad blocker extensions/plugins installed on your browser**, as they will obviously block this one too if `https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/preview_iframe.php` is not on your whitelist.

Anyway, this is a workaround for what I was trying to accomplish, but I won't mark it as the correct answer to my question, since that issue is still around.